# How do you move from a login screen that has no navigation drawer to a home screen that does have a navigation drawer in python kivymd?

Tags: python, navigation-drawer, kivymd

I have a login screen that has no navigation drawer. If the user logs in successfully, I want them to be taken to a home screen that has the navigation drawer. I am able to code these screens separately. I am failing to transition from the login screen, which has no navigation drawer, to the home screen which does have the navigation drawer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: All you need to do is set up a screen manager and on the function that logs the user in, if the login is successful, then call the screenmanager switch_to function to go back to the home screen. Just look up the screenmanager in kivy docs